# Firebase Function returning Undefined values, even with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, asynchronous, promise

I'm new on Firebase, I've a simple program that fetches product information using "ProductID".
Here's the hierarchy:
[PRODUCT CHILD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NNHI.png)

The problem is, when I use this function, it returns undefined values. I know it's asynchronous, and I've tried adding promises, but still in vain. Here's it:

```
function getProduct(prID){
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("server/products/" + prID);
    let rData = '';
    ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    rData = snapshot.val();
    }, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
return rData;
```

Calling the same function with same values returns the product, but calling for different parameter values, it returns undefined.
I've tried using (in a function *getProductPromise(prID)* ), I changed above function to:

```
function getProductPromise(id) {
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("server/products/" + id);
    let rData = '';
    return ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    return snapshot.val();
  });
}
```

it is still returning undefined values. What could be the possible way to ensure that some values are returned. 
Thanks.

Comment: as a side note: in that second piece of code, having `return` on a line by itself more often than not (as is the case here) results in the code being interpreted as `return;` - because javascript works in mysterious ways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're having some scoping issues in the first example, so not sure if it would ever work as you're expecting. Promises are your best bet. You can try something like:

```
function fetchProductById (id) {
     var db = admin.database()
     var collectionRef = db.ref('server/products')
     var ref = collectionRef.child(id)
     return ref.once('value')
         .then((snapshot) => {
             return snapshot.val()
         })

} 

// then to implement:
fetchProductById('abc')
    .then((result) => {
        console.log('the result is', result)
    })
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Awei :)
Just one question here. How can I use a variable inside the `.then` part?
i.e I'm trying this:
`var productInfo;
fetchProductById('abc')
    .then((result) => {
        productInfo = result
    })`

but it stores no values in Productinfo.

Comment: What you really need is a way to update the user interface when `.then()` is called. What do you want to do with the results when you receive them? I can better answer your question if I understand what you're trying to do w/ the result.

Comment: I'm using productInfo in rest of the code to display info to users. Like, productInfo.name etc. in different functions.

Comment: I just want to store value to a variable that I will use in rest of my code. I can access the result in `.then ` part, I want to access it in outside of `.then` too

Comment: So, in that case, I would look at something like `baobab` (https://github.com/Yomguithereal/baobab) or `flyd` (https://github.com/paldepind/flyd/) which allow you to react to changes in state